# How can I add my own style property and values?

Tags: javascript

Can I make a javascript function so that the property and value would work in stylesheet?

So the following would work:

```
.selector{
   myproperty: myvalue1; /* myvalue1, myvalue2, myvalue3 */
}
```

Suppose, I would define the myvalue1, myvalue2, and myvalue3 in js for eg. sets element's background-color to red, green and blue respectively and now defining it in stylesheet it should be able to set div's background color to red,green, and blue at their respective.

```
if('myproperty' in document.body.style){
  //don't do anything
}else{
    //do stuff here
    //something like this
    document.body.style.myproperty = [value1,value2,vlaue3]
}
```

Comment: do you mean injecting css stylesheet as string using javascript?

Comment: I don't think you can add your own custom css properties

Comment: Can you give an example of 'myproperty'?

Comment: I'd have thought you'd be able to ask a question a little better as a 10K+ user. What is your issue here? As far as I can tell you want to add some styles to a style sheet; what does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: @oGeez I wanted to know that could I make my own custom css properties...

Comment: That would do what? Correspond to other, *real* properties?

Comment: What good is a custom css property if no browser knows how to render it?

Comment: What does it have to do with javascript? Do you want to be able retrieve the value of your custom property using javascript?

Comment: @Cameron yes, I want to define my custom property and value so that I can use later it in stylesheet...

Comment: By the sounds of it you are wanting to do something impossible... I'm still unsure exactly how to help, sorry. Perhaps you should check out sass/scss http://sass-lang.com - it has some pretty nifty features such as variables and mixins which might help you.

Comment: @oGeez yes, you are right. As other style property I want to create my own ....

Comment: So you would like JavaScript to grab your stylesheet, parse it, and map your custom properties to real ones?

Comment: @C-linkNepal you could probably benefit from learning sass then by the sounds of it. Check out the "variables" in the guide here http://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing, but you might be able to use jQuery's `.css` function.

```
$('.selector').css('myproperty','myvalue1');
```

Comment: bit of a stab in the dark here...